# Why is there now col-lg-offset element in the bootstrap-3 css?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I downloaded (twice) twitter bootstrap -3 compiled css and javascript file from http://getbootstrap.com

Adding the col-lg-offset-2 class is not showing any difference to the html page. I looked up the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css file that i downloaded. I am unable to find col-lg-offset in either one of them. On the http://getbootstrap.com/css/ page they suggest to add this class to offset the margin of the `<div>`.

What is wrong?

Comment: Does your 3 download contain `col-offset-*`? Bootstrap 3 is still a work in progress (no final release yet) and I think the change to `col-lg-offset-*` is very recent. The `http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css` build has the new `col-lg-offset-*` classes.

Comment: Do you not recommend using bootstrap 3? I am switching so that, i can get better support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download a  current snapshot from git to get the latest. The precompiled download is outdated.

The issue is being discussed https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9138