# Bootstrap 3 image gallery overrides

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 RC1, and I am having trouble getting the image gallery set up properly.

Problem 1 - the `ul` is adding a `padding-left` or `margin-left`. What do I need to override to remove it?

Problem 2 - each `li` is spanning the container instead of being limited by its `span4`class. I would like to have two images per row.

I added an image below showing where the problems are.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div id="allVideos">
        <ul class="thumbnails">
          <li class="span4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="<%= thumbnail_image %>">
              <div class="caption">
                <a data-attribute="<%= _id %>" class="delete">X</a>
                <h3><a class="video_item"><%= title %></h3></h3>
                </div>
              </div>  
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**IMAGE**
[image]

Comment: Does simply adding `padding-left: 0;` and `margin-left: 0;` for the CSS not fix your first problem?

Comment: Also, when you use a container in bootstrap it automatically creates margins on the left and right does it not? I haven't experimented with Bootstrap 3 yet so I am unsure of whether or not that has changed.

Comment: @MitulP91 Thanks, that corrected problem 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap 2.3 used the "span" classes (`span4` in your example), and Bootstrap 3.0 uses "col-X" classes (`col-lg-X` in your example). The "span" classes no longer exist.

Problem 1 - Use the `list-unstyled` class to remove left/right margin from `<li>` children. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-lists

Problem 2 - Drop the span class and use Bootstrap 3's new classes:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled row">
    <li class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <a class="delete">X</a>
          <h3><a class="video_item">Howdy</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <a class="delete">X</a>
          <h3><a class="video_item">Howdy</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <a class="delete">X</a>
          <h3><a class="video_item">Howdy</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your image to make it responsive:

```
<img src="<%= thumbnail_image %>" class="img-responsive">
```

(ref: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-responsive-images)

For the padding and margin, can you just add your own styles to override?

```
.thumbnails{ margin-left:0; padding-left: 0;}
```

Comment: Thanks. The images are actually responsive. Its the `thumbnail` class that adding all the whitespace between the image and container span.

Answer (score 0):

Also I recommend you look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195161/why-is-there-now-col-lg-offset-element-in-the-bootstrap-3-css)

It seems Twitter Bootstrap 3 is still under construction and I think the `col-lg-12` class is still having some issues. I only briefly glanced at it though.

Hope this helps.